# How to get a reference to an element in the template

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to initialize a chart using angularJs (v1.5.8) but I am unable to initialize a new chart object like below as shown in the [instructions](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-selecting-the-correct-build)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { ...
```

because I am unable to get a reference to the html element in the template. How to get it ?

```
angular.module("dashboard", ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.component("exceptionChart", {
    template: "<canvas class='{{$ctrl.class}}'></canvas>",
    bindings: { class: '@' },
    controller: function(){
        // how do I get a reference to canvas
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your controller you can inject `$element` service to get access to `template`.

Ideally you should access that `$element` inside `$postLink()` lifecycle hook of component which will ensure that all the descendant directive has compiled.

```
controller: function($element){
    // how do I get a reference to canvas
    this.$postLink = function() {
       console.log($element)
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside `$element` what should I be looking for ?  is it this `$element[0].children[0]` ?

Comment: `$element.find('canvas)` should be fine

Comment: I tried it and I am getting `$element` as `undefined` inside `$postLink`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I tried but its giving me some kind of error, here is the fiddle if  you want to see it https://jsfiddle.net/chohpcpu/  . Meanwhile I will look for a working sample fiddle and edit it

Comment: They are all giving me the same error, I don't understand why, I am pretty new to angularJS

Comment: Hey i had mistake, I should have remove $element from $postLink function(mistakenly I had it there), try updated